# re-write URL under a subdirectory

Tags: apache

I have a few rewrite rule problems with following simple URL.
`PHP $_GET['id']` is not assigned.

URL

```
https://dev.sys/member/profile.php?id=252972
```

expected clean URL

```
https://dev.sys/member/profile/252972
```

Rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)? page.php?id=$1`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?:...)` is a **non-grouping match**. While it will match, `$1` will not be created.

That, and you're rewriting to the wrong script.